# Why does this TeXForm cause many errors?

Tags: functions, bugs, latex, matex

**Bug introduced in 13.0 or earlier. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

Why do I get this error? I don't do any calculation with this. I just want to use TeXForm and then wrap MaTeX around it.

```
TeXForm["\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \
\(2\)]\)\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-\*FractionBox[\
\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]\), FractionBox[\(\[Pi]\), \
\(2\)]]\)\!\(\*TagBox[FractionBox[RowBox[{SuperscriptBox[\"r\", \
\"2\"], \" \", RowBox[{\"(\", RowBox[{\"cos\", \" \", \"\[Theta]\"}], \
\")\"}], \" \", \
SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{\"(\", RowBox[{RowBox[{\"-\", \"1\"}], \"+\", \
RowBox[{\"r\", \" \", RowBox[{\"(\", RowBox[{\"sin\", \" \", \"\
\[Theta]\"}], \")\"}]}]}], \
\")\"}], \"3\"]}], RowBox[{\"1\", \"+\", SuperscriptBox[\"r\", \
\"2\"]}]],HoldForm]\)dr d\[Theta] = -\!\(\*FractionBox[\(16\\ \
\[Pi]\), \(3\)]\)"]
```

[image]

And this is the result when I run in another computer.

[image]

Comment: Why do you use TeXForm on a string?

Comment: @CarlWoll I think I tried without string but I got error so I added the string mark.

Comment: The infinite recursion is a bug, pure and simple. I will report it.

Comment: The answer to the question raised in the subject header, which I'm sure I'll need to delete soon, is "Because TeXForm hates us and wants us to be miserable".

Comment: Equivalent to the above: "Because there's a fundamental law of nature; conservation of misery"

Comment: @bmf `TexForm` breaks this law by actually increasing misery. Think of it as entropy I guess.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau priceless!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In light of the comment by @Daniel Lichtblau the following is a workaround to the bug that is present**

**Edit: addressing all the comments**

[image: edit1]

The code is given below:

```
MaTeX[TeXForm[
  HoldForm@
    Integrate[(r^2 Cos[\[Theta]] (-1 + r (Sin[\[Theta]]))^3)/(
     1 + r^2), {r, 0, 2}, {\[Theta], -Pi/2, Pi/2}] == 
   Integrate[(r^2 Cos[\[Theta]] (-1 + r (Sin[\[Theta]]))^3)/(
    1 + r^2), {r, 0, 2}, {\[Theta], -Pi/2, Pi/2}]]]
```

---

**Original answer**

---

I am not 100% sure why it happens. I checked that by copying and pasting your code in my notebook, I also had the errors. I think it has to do with the `HoldForm` and perhaps the `RowBox`. See below:

I started coding your expression afresh. It worked fine.

[image: res]

The code used

```
TeXForm["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\)], \
\(2\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \
\(-\*FractionBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]\)], FractionBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]]\
\) \!\(\*FractionBox[\(\((cos\\\ \[Theta])\) \*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\
\) + r \((sin\\\ \[Theta])\))\), \(3\)]\), \(1 + \*SuperscriptBox[\(r\
\), \(2\)]\)]\) dr d\[Theta]=-\!\(\*FractionBox[\(16  \[Pi]\), \(3\)]\
\)"]
```

Note that I grabbed the code posted here and tried it in a fresh kernel and worked with no issues.

[image: res2]

Comment: thanks, your code works in my another computer but if I copied my code above then I also got error.

Comment: @hana yes, it makes sense. It probably has something to do with `HoldForm` and/or `RowBox` as I mentioned in my answer. Not sure how you got those though.

Comment: Oh, yea, I forgot to remove it. I used it to replace Cos[x] to cos(x) form.

Comment: @hana ok, so it seems that this is causing the issue. I wrapped my code around `MaTex` and works fine. You can try `MaTeX[TeXForm[codefromabove]]` just to make sure.

Comment: Somehow the upper limit of the second integral `π/2`  located offside.

Comment: @hana can you have a look at the edit I just provided and let me know what you think? Is this what you wanted to get?

Comment: oh, that is great and I didn't get that was what you were saying.

Comment: @hana Glad I was able to help :)